# Dyalog APL: what is the problem with loops?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I'm trying to process data received via API using a loop, but the loop is very slow. Is this a Dyalog bug?

```
res←getBinanceSymbols

 res←⍬
 baseToken←'USDT'

 tmpSymbols←(⎕JSON(HttpCommand.Get'api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo').Data).symbols

 :For sym1 :In tmpSymbols
     ⎕←sym1.symbol
 :EndFor
```

**see here →** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUl4oixd3Ds

Anyway, my complete task is to form pairs of the form XXXYYY XXXZZZ ZZZYYY, and I've tried to do this using nested loops (see below), but it takes forever...

```
 res←getBinanceSymbols

 res←⍬
 baseToken←'USDT'

 tmpSymbols←(⎕JSON(HttpCommand.Get'api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo').Data).symbols

 :For sym1 :In tmpSymbols
     Sym1_Token1←sym1.baseAsset
     Sym1_Token2←sym1.quoteAsset

     :If Sym1_Token1≡baseToken
         :For sym2 :In tmpSymbols
             Sym2_Token1←sym2.baseAsset
             Sym2_Token2←sym2.quoteAsset

             :If Sym1_Token1≡Sym2_Token2
                 :For sym3 :In tmpSymbols
                     Sym3_Token1←sym3.baseAsset
                     Sym3_Token2←sym3.quoteAsset

                     :If Sym2_Token1≡Sym3_Token1
                     :AndIf Sym3_Token2≡Sym1_Token2
                     :AndIf Sym1_Token1≢Sym1_Token2
                     :AndIf Sym2_Token1≢Sym1_Token1
                     :AndIf Sym2_Token1≢Sym1_Token2

                         res,←⊂((Sym1_Token1⍪Sym1_Token2)(Sym2_Token1⍪Sym1_Token2)(Sym2_Token1⍪Sym1_Token2))

                     :EndIf
                 :EndFor
             :EndIf
         :EndFor
     :EndIf
 :EndFor
```

**Question 1:** Why is the loop so slow? I work on a computer with Intel Core i5 11th and 40GB DDR4. It's just unthinkable!

**Question 2:** How can I solve my problem without resorting to nested loops? In a more the APL way

Comment: While I suspect something else too, there seems to be well over 2000 `tmpSymbols` and you have three nested for loops, potentially going around the loop over 1×10¹⁰…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for unreasonable slowness is what I call a *dangling reference*. Dyalog objects contain a reference to their parent object. `tmpSymbols` therefore contains a reference to `Data` but `Data` doesn't otherwise live anywhere per se. This continuously causes the garbage collector to kick in and investigate whether `Data` can be expunged, only to find, every time, that it cannot, because `tmpSymbols` needs it to remain in existence. It is this contant garbage collection activity that is the cause of the slowdown.

So, how do you work around this? Keep a direct reference to `Data`, as then there's no question that it doesn't need to be expunged:

```
 res←getBinanceSymbols

 res←⍬
 baseToken←'USDT'

⍝ Insert "data←" ↓
 tmpSymbols←(data←⎕JSON(HttpCommand.Get'api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo').Data).symbols

 :For sym1 :In tmpSymbols
     ⎕←sym1.symbol
 :EndFor
```